# How to force openssl/s_client to send a keyshare for the specific elliptic curve (secp256r1)?

Tags: tls, openssl

I want to test my server application (TLS 1.3) using `s_client` program from the `openssl` library and I need to get from the `s_client` a keyshare in the 1st ClientHello for `secp256r1` (it proposes `x25519` now).
 Could you tell me, which command line options in `s_client` should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-curves` or (synonym) `-groups` to specify all 'supported' groups, with the one you want offered in key_share FIRST, e.g. `-curves secp256r1:secp384r1:X25519`.

Comment: @dave_thomson_085, thank you very much - it helped! By the way, could you tell me - is server certificate sending a mandatory step in TLS 1.3 handshaking ? Or it can be skipped ?

Comment: LUN: that's a different question, and not really crypto, but yes server cert is mandatory in 1.3 except when using PSK which in practice means except for 'resumption'; see 2nd para of [rfc8446 4.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446.html#section-4.4.2)